# Where is Bootstrap 4's SASS files?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, gruntjs, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I followed Bootstrap 4' installation guide from source and 'grunt dist' is supposed to build the SASS files but they are nowhere.  Why are they missing?

Answer (score 0):

did you download your file from here:

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/

As there is a scss folder, which will contain your necessary files